# Lambda function containing if statement

Tags: python, lambda

Is there any way how to code recursive function containing if with lamba?
Is possible to rewrite this using lambda.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return 1
    return x * factorial(x - 1)

print(factorial(5))
```

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do that?

Comment: just asking if it's possible

Comment: Dear @BrenBarn I was asking if is possible to use if statements in lambda.

Comment: @gml: In that case, you have your answer below.  It is not possible to use *any* statements in a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, or at least not without assigning the function to a variable and then using that name to call it. But you still cannot use any statements in the function.

In any case, don't do that. A `lambda` function is *exactly* like a normal `def` function in Python besides the restriction that it cannot contain statements.

The only reason to use a lambda in Python is to avoid defining an named function if you just need a simple callable returning some value.

Comment: what about `>>> fa= lambda x :1 if x <= 1 else  x*fa(x-1)` ?

Comment: @Kasra - That's different.  There are no statements in the code you posted (except for the assignment of course).  The OP was asking if he can put a statement in a lambda, which is not possible.

Comment: Updated my answer to mention this case.

Comment: @iCodez ohum , yep , i think so !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible for this specific case.

```
>>> factorial = lambda x: 1 if x < 1 else x * factorial(x - 1)
>>> factorial(5)
120
```

I wouldn't recommend it though. A standard function definition seems far more readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = lambda i: 1 if i<=1 else i * l(i-1)
>>> l(5)
120
>>> 5*4*3*2*1
120
```